# Excel VBA - Copy mutiple column not in sequence order

Tags: vba, excel, range

I want to copy from one sheet into another. The macro should recognize the worksheet via name:

```
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim NewEnd As Long
Dim NewEnd2 As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheets("CALC").Select

Worksheets("CALC").Range("B5:J25000").ClearContents

For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(wB.Name, 4) = "15B2" Then
        Set Wb1 = wB
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not Wb1 Is Nothing Then
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

    With Wb1.Sheets("Data")
        Set rngToCopy = .Range("F7, H7, N7", .Cells(.rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    End With
    wb2.Sheets("CALC").Range("B5:D5").Resize(rngToCopy.rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value
End If
```

This line gives me an error:

```
 Set rngToCopy = .Range("F7, H7, N7", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
```

How can I copy mutiple columns in this case?

Comment: Get the lastrow from one column ('F' for example) into a variable and build you Adress-String for your range from that: `.Range("F7:F" & lastrow & ",H7:H" & lstrow.... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Union` to merge multiple columns to 1 `Range`.

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data from column "F"

Set rngToCopy = Application.Union(.Range("F7:F" & LastRow), .Range("H7:H" & LastRow), .Range("N7:N" & LastRow))

rngToCopy.Copy
wb2.Sheets("CALC").Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Hi Shai, now the macro copies the column F 3 times :O.

Comment: @Bluesector try the updated code below, worked with my tests

Comment: Worked! Thank you!